# Create new table with calculated data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to do an regression analysis through my data chunks. For that I need to find out various values. For each data set I need to get `N:count(X)` `sumX` `sumY` `sumX*X` etc.

Separately I wrote queries for those operations like

```
SELECT COUNT(X) FROM table_name
SELECT SUM(X*X) FROM table_name
```

I need to create another table which a row contain `count(X)`, `sumX` , `sumX*X` etc. How can I write that kind of query?

Comment: You mean a [`CREATE TABLE _____ AS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html) query?

Comment: yes, I need that kind of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple aggregates to the same query and use `create table as`:

```
create table yournewtable as
select count(x) cnt, sum(x*x) sumxx, sum(x) sumx
from table_name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/224ec/1)

This will return you a single row.  If you need to break it apart, look into `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE` first and then use `INSERT INTO`

```
CREATE TABLE yourTableName
(
  col1 int,
  col2 int,
  col3 int
);

INSERT INTO yourTableName (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(X) FROM table_name),
  (SELECT SUM(X) from table_name),
  (SELECT SUM(X*X) from table_name)
```